# adobe livecycle address in use

Tags: adobe, port, livecycle

I'm trying to start Adobe LiveCycle on Linux OS. Firstly, I started mysql, then I try use command "bash jBoss start".
However I'm getting some errors, for example:

2014-07-07 14:26:13,802 WARN  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.JBossWeb] Failed to startConnectors
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "jboss.web";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1139)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.JBossWeb.startConnectors(JBossWeb.java:584)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.JBossWeb.handleNotification(JBossWeb.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.notification.NotificationListenerProxy.invoke(NotificationListenerProxy.java:153)
    at $Proxy40.handleNotification(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.JBossNotificationBroadcasterSupport.handleNotification(JBossNotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:127)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.JBossNotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(JBossNotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:108)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.sendNotification(ServerImpl.java:916)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:497)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

When I start netstat I tells me this port isn't used.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Adobe Livecycle got suspended. Stopping it and starting again worked.